# Django article format: why the articles I posted are showed in a mess?

Tags: python, html, django, backend

I tried use django/admin to post my article. But when I checked the articles I posted, I found they were in a mess. the articles contain html labels and other unkonwn characters. I don't why this happens. So could anyone help me check what's the problem?

[image: This is what my blog showed]

[image: This is the origin article I copied from Google]

Comment: Use the [`safe` filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/templates/builtins/#safe), like: `{{ your_content_body | safe }}`.

Comment: @xyres, Thanks a lot. it finally works!